Define if the statement: ∀x(A(x) ≡ B(x)) ~ (∀x A(x) ≡ ∀x B(x)) is always true
There is a statement: $$∀x(A(x) \equiv B(x)) \sim (∀x A(x) \equiv ∀x B(x))$$ that seems to be true in all models, but unfortunately I can't think of an idea to proove that, except this, but I am not sure whether it makes sense...
$$∀x(A(x) \equiv B(x)) \sim (∀x A(x) \equiv ∀x B(x))$$
is the same as:
$$ M ⊨ ∀x(A(x) \equiv B(x)) \iff M ⊨ (∀x A(x) \equiv ∀x B(x))$$
where M is a Model, hence:
$M ⊨ (∀x A(x) \equiv ∀x B(x))$
is true in M. Consider 2 cases:
$1) M ⊨ ∀x (A(x))$ and $M ⊨ ∀x (B(x))$ $\iff$ $∀a \in M ⊨ (A(a))$ and $∀b \in M ⊨ (B(b))$ $\iff$ $∀c \in M ⊨ (A(c) \land B(c))$ $\iff$ $M ⊨ ∀x (A(x) \land B(x))$
$2) M ⊨ ∀x (¬A(x))$ and $M ⊨ ∀x(¬B(x))$ $\iff$ $∀a \in M ⊨ ( ¬A(a))$ and $∀b \in M ⊨ ( ¬B(b))$ $\iff$ $∀c \in M ⊨ (¬A(c) \land ¬B(c))$ $\iff$ $M ⊨ ∀x (¬A(x) \land ¬B(x))$
Hence, we can say that:
$M ⊨ ∀x(A(x) \equiv B(x))$
I am sure that it is incorrect proof, as I made some questionable assumptions out of nowhere and I completely ignored the definition of the logical equivalence.
We only started predicate logic, so it's unlikely that some advanced theorems are used here.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Cheers!

This is not true; only the $\implies$ direction holds. Consider the natural numbers with $A(x) \equiv x\text{ is even}$, $B(x) \equiv x\text{ is odd}$.
